# iOS Autolayout: Oddly expand-animation of UITextView inside an UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, uikit, uitextview

I'm trying to animate the height constraint of a UITextView inside a UIScrollView. When the user taps the "toggle" button, the text should appear in animation from top to bottom. But somehow UIKit fades in the complete view.

[image: Animation]

To ensure the "dynamic" height depending on the intrinsic content-size, I deactivate the height constraint set to zero.

```
 @IBAction func toggle() {
    layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: { [weak self] in

        guard let self = self else {
            return
        }

        if self.expanded {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([self.height].compactMap { $0 })
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([self.height].compactMap { $0 })
        }
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
    expanded.toggle()
}
```

The full code of this example is available on my GitHub Repo: [ScrollAnimationExample](https://github.com/jbrunhuber/ScrollAnimationExample)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel`? And, are you targeting iOS 13+ or earlier?

Comment: Hi @DonMag, thank you for your answer. There's no reason for the `UITextView`. We could have used a multi line `UILabel` too. We're currently targeting iOS 11.2+ but thinking about going to iOS 13+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing your GitHub repo...

The issue is due to the `view` that is animated. You want to run `.animate()` on the "top-most" view in the hierarchy.

To do this, you can either create a new property of your `ExpandableView`, such as:

```
var topMostView: UIView?
```

and then set that property from your view controller, or...

To keep your class encapsulated, let it find the top-most view. Replace your `toggle()` func with:

```
@IBAction func toggle() {

    // we need to run .animate() on the "top" superview

    // make sure we have a superview
    guard self.superview != nil else {
        return
    }

    // find the top-most superview
    var mv: UIView = self
    while let s = mv.superview {
        mv = s
    }

    // UITextView has subviews, one of which is a _UITextContainerView,
    //  which also has a _UITextCanvasView subview.
    // If scrolling is disabled, and the TextView's height is animated to Zero,
    //  the CanvasView's height is instantly set to Zero -- so it disappears instead of animating.

    // So, when the view is "expanded" we need to first enable scrolling,
    //  and then animate the height (to Zero)
    // When the view is NOT expanded, we first disable scrolling
    //  and then animate the height (to its intrinsic content height)

    if expanded {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([height].compactMap { $0 })
    } else {
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([height].compactMap { $0 })
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
        mv.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

    expanded.toggle()

}
```